# Layout in R Shiny app that include R Markdown file

Tags: shiny, r-markdown

I am facing a problem with the layout in R Shiny when I use the R Markdown file inside it I get the final result in a wired layout size (small and only in the middle of the screen ) as shown in the following photo:
[image]

Attached to you the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(knitr)

ui <- 
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title ='Virtual Excursion'), 
  
  dashboardSidebar( sliderTextInput(
    inputId = "mySliderText", 
    label = "Story line", 
    grid = TRUE, 
    force_edges = TRUE,
    choices = c('1','2')
  )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      column(9,  
             box(
               title = "Operations ", 
               closable = FALSE, 
               width = 9,
               status = "primary", 
               solidHeader = FALSE, 
               collapsible = TRUE,
               uiOutput("operations")
             )
      )
    ), 
    fluidRow(
      column(9, 
             box(
               title = "Challenges", 
               closable = FALSE, 
               width = 9,
               status = "primary", 
               solidHeader = FALSE, 
               collapsible = TRUE,
               uiOutput("challenges")
             )
      ) 
    )
  )
)


 server <- function(input, output,session){

 output$operations <- renderUI({
 req(input$mySliderText==1)

 HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit('trial1.rmd', quiet = TRUE)))
 })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Could you please guide me on how to fix this problem!

Comment: Can't reproduce it without the `trial1.rmd` file. May you post that?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are including an full html file within an html page. The conflicts between the two pages is causing the display problem. You need to output an html fragment which excludes the heading. Add `fragment.only = TRUE` to your markdown render function.

```
HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit("trial1.rmd", quiet=T),fragment.only = T))
```

You can also add `output: html_fragment` in your yaml section inside the rmd file for good measure.